# Authenticate data before decryption with GCM and OpenSSL

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes, aes-gcm

I'm using AES-GCM to decrypt some data. I have some additional authenticated data (AAD), the authentication tag and the actual encrypted data.

What I need to be able to do is authenticate the AAD and encrypted data before actually decrypting it.

I know that OpenSSL's `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex` function will return 0 if the data fails authentication, but there doesn't appear to be a way to verify the data without actually decrypting it.

The reason I need to do this is that my encrypted data could be quite large, so I'd like to only decrypt it pieces at a time using `EVP_DecryptUpdate`. However, doing this would provide with with data I can't be sure is authentic.

What I need to be able to do is authenticate all of the AAD and encrypted data, and then use `EVP_DecryptUpdate` to decrypt it parts at a time. I could decrypt all the data at once to authenticate it, although this would add additional computing time to my application which I want to avoid.

Comment: In order to authenticate anything a full pass must be done over the ciphertext in GCM. You could encrypt your plaintext in chunks in order to authenticate them separately or you could opt in for CBC mode with multiple HMACs over different parts of the ciphertext.

Comment: That's what I'm asking: how to authenticate all the data in a full pass without needing to also decrypt it.